# Python slice return a wrong values?

Tags: python

I am learning python, and I have a problem with list slice. when I try to get all element at the third position, I got the wrong one:

```
l = [9, 0, 7, 1, 7, 5, 5, 9, 8, 0]
th = l[::3]
>> [9, 1, 5, 0]
```

but in my logic it should be:

```
>> [7, 5, 8]
```

Why it returns  a wrong result?

Comment: You are stepping 3 starting from the 0 index so you get what you ask for, to get what you want would be `l[2::3]`, if it makes it simpler you are basically doing `l[0:len(l):3]`

Comment: `th = l[2::3]` following your logic

Comment: 0 % 3 = 0, 3 % 3 = 0...etc the math works out.

Comment: @kuhe you can check the stackoverflow post [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation), there is some useful answers about python index/slice notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`l[::3]` means start at 0 and go till the end of list and step 3 each time
so at each step, it will output item at indices `0, 3, 6, 9`. Which corresponds to the result that Python returned back. try `l[2::3]` if you want your desired output (every third element starting from the third).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Python slice operator starts at the first index (index 0), while you want it to start at the third (index 2). `[2::3]` should get what you want, as this will tell it to start at index 2 and take it and every third element after.